# How to compute gradients in tensorflow when the dependence on the loss is complex

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to train "manually" a tensorflow network, but the dependence of the loss on the parameters is the following (I will talk about two networks, the one I want to train is NET1):

- Given some input, NET1 gives me an output
- The output from NET1 are imposed as weights of NET2 that, let's say, gives an output "u"
- The loss is computed as some function of "u"
- Now, I want to compute the gradient of the loss with respect to the weights of NET1.

However, the gradients I compute are always zeros.

I tried with the following approach:

```
def train_step(self, input_weights):

   with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
       pred_weights = self.NET1(input_weights)

       weights = self.transform_weights_from_array(pred_weights)
       for j in range(len(weights)):
           self.NET2.weights[j].assign(weights[j])

       u = self.NET2(SOME_INPUT)
       loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.abs(u))

   gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.NET1.trainable_variables,
                             unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)
```

where "transform_weights_from_array" is the following:

```
def transform_weights_from_array(self, w_arr): 

    W = self.NET2.weights
    w_shaped = []
    k = 0
    for i, arr in enumerate(W):
        n = 1
        for dim in arr.shape:
            n *= dim
        w_shaped.append(tf.reshape(w_arr[k:k + n], arr.shape))
        k += n
    return w_shaped
```

it simply transforms the weights from the vector shape to the list shape.
However, the gradients are not computed as I would have expected.